# What is "lettercase" in "CREATE DATABASE" statement?

Tags: mysql

In the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), it is said:

> Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase
>   specified in the `CREATE TABLE` or `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

I Googled a lot to know how to use "lettercase" in a specific `CREATE DATABASE` statement but didn't find it.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but doesn't that just mean that if you type `CREATE TABLE cAsEThIngY` it will save it as a file with that casing. (and that is relevant as some filesystems are, and some are not case sensitive). So previous statement will result in a file with casing `cAsEThIngY` and not all lowercase or anything like that. Still, as said, not really sure.

Comment: You want to know why we type keywords caps???

Comment: That would make sense, maybe I was just mis-interpreting that part of the doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table and Database names **case sensitivity depends on system where MySQL is running**. Names are stored in separated file names. So for example file names on windows are not case sensitive but on linux file names are case sensitive.

**Linux**
Table and Database names are case sensitive

**Windows**
Table and Database names are case insensitive

Comment: Thanks for the precision.   That explains why we can't set the equivalent of lower-case-table-names per database.

Answer (score 1):

it means that table and database names are cAsESeNsItIvE